# perl regex square brackets and single quotes

Tags: regex, perl, brackets

Have this string:

```
ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145722
```

The data is repeated.

I need to remove the []' characters from the data so it looks like this:

```
ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,TEST,ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,TEST,ABC.1000145722
```

I'm also trying to split the data to assign it to variables as seen below:

```
my($currency, $strike, $tenor, $tenor2,$ado_symbol) = split /,/, $_;
```

This works for everything but the ['TEST'] section. Should I remove the []' characters first then keep my split the same or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that's useful to know is this - that `split` takes a regex. (It'll even let you capture, but that'll insert into the returned list, which is why I've got `(?:` for non capturing groups)

I observe your data only has `['` right next to the delimiter - so how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /(?:\'])?,(?:\[\')?/; 
  print Dumper \@fields;
}

__DATA__
ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145722
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ABC',
          '-0.5',
          '10Y',
          '10Y',
          'TEST',
          'ABC.1000145721ABC',
          '-0.5',
          '20Y',
          '10Y',
          'TEST',
          'ABC.1000145722'
        ];
```

Comment: awesome `Something that's useful to know is this - that split takes a regex`

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145722";

$str =~ s/\['|'\]//g;

print $str;
```

output is

```
ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,TEST,ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,TEST,ABC.1000145722
```

Now you can split.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up `$ado_symbol` after split:

```
$ado_symbol =~ s/^\['//;
$ado_symbol =~ s/'\]$//;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global regex match to find all substrings that are not a comma, a single quote, or a square bracket

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $s = q{ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145722};

my @data = $s =~ /[^,'\[\]]+/g;

my ( $currency, $strike, $tenor, $tenor2, $ado_symbol ) = @data;

print "\$currency   = $currency\n";
print "\$strike     = $strike\n";
print "\$tenor      = $tenor\n";
print "\$tenor2     = $tenor2\n";
print "\$ado_symbol = $ado_symbol\n";
```

#### output

```
$currency   = ABC
$strike     = -0.5
$tenor      = 10Y
$tenor2     = 10Y
$ado_symbol = TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

```
my $str = "ABC,-0.5,10Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145721ABC,-0.5,20Y,10Y,['TEST'],ABC.1000145722";

my ($currency, $strike, $tenor, $tenor2,$ado_symbol) = map{ s/[^A-Z0-9\.-]//g; $_} split ',',$str;
print "$currency, $strike, $tenor, $tenor2, $ado_symbol",$/;
```

Output is:

```
ABC, -0.5, 10Y, 10Y, TEST
```